# In my existing project i seen a peace of code which is in SASS file. but i didn't get why they are using these prefixes like &. .. in SASS

Tags: css, sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/przOt.png)

in the above code line no 34 & 44 they used &. signs before class name may I know the purpose of those.

Comment: In my SASS code, few classes are declared like &. sign.
  &.resize {
    .grid {
      section {
        .content {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Answer (score 0):

When the Sass processor turns that into CSS, the ampersand (&) will be replaced with the selectors that it's nested inside. It's shorthand for writing 'repeat the above selectors here'. So it's a quick way to create long, specific nested CSS selectors.

Comment: In a few other cases, we have .. instead of &.  same purpose here also..?

Comment: like @import '../components/palettes/palettes-colors';

Comment: The two dots mean 'go up one folder'. It's part of the path to a partial, a snippet of Sass code that is being imported.

Comment: @each $animal, $color, $cursor in (puma, black, default),

                                  (sea-slug, blue, pointer),

                                  (egret, white, move) {
  .#{$animal}-icon {
    background-image: url('/images/#{$animal}.png');
    border: 2px solid $color;
    cursor: $cursor;
  }
}
 in the above code we have an image url, in that we are using # as prefix to variable what is the purpose of # sign there

Comment: That's interpolation. Sass will insert the variable's value there as a string. Here are the docs: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation